# How can I manually run a Git pre-commit hook, without attempting a commit?

Tags: githooks

I just want to be able to run it to see if the code in my working tree passes it, without actually attempting a commit.

Comment: Note: Git 2.36 (Q1 2022) will come with [`git hook run [--ignore-missing] <hook-name> [-- <hook-args>]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101716/6309)!

Comment: Late to the party, but it's a popular question, yet percieved to be ambigious if you read the comments in the answers below. Please add a line or two describing if you're after native shell functionality or something like python based pre-commit from pre-commit.com.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Just run the `pre-commit` script through the shell:

```
bash .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Comment: Oh it's that easy. Also seems they are directly executable, so you can do `./.git/hooks/precommit`

Comment: Yes, it is also directly executable.

Comment: This won't detect/correct all problems in all existing files - for that, you want `pre-commit run --all-files`, see my answer here.

Comment: If you find that this doesn't do anything, don't forget to `git add` the files!

Comment: @javabrett note that this answer does not refer to the python pre-commit package but rather the native git pre-commit hook. Your command will not work for someone who just uses native git hooks

Comment: This is perfect, also works for any hook, like pre-push hook ! Thanks !

Comment: Note: you need to be in your repository root dir for this to work.  E.g. If you're in a subdirectory and do `../.git/hooks/pre-commit`, it won't recognize the files you've `add`ed to your git workspace.

Comment: This answer assumed that `pre-commit` is a bash shell script.  It doesn't have to be.

Comment: .git/hooks/pre-commit must be a bash script: git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables "Git always runs inside a bash shell"

Comment: Answer does not work in the case of working on a submodule.

Executing via `pre-commit` per @javabrett does.

Comment: 1 more note: This .git/hooks/pre-commit does only exist once per worktree, so if you use this feature and your are not on your "main" worktree: go and find your .git/hooks/pre-commit in your main worktree.

Answer (score 118):

There's a Python package for this available [here](https://pre-commit.com). Per the [usage documentation](https://pre-commit.com/#usage):

> If you want to manually run all pre-commit hooks on a repository, run `pre-commit run --all-files`. To run individual hooks use `pre-commit run <hook_id>`.

So `pre-commit run --all-files` is what the OP is after.

Comment: Note this pre-commit isn't the git pre-commit. Rather, it's a python package from https://pre-commit.com that installs a git pre-commit script. However, the python package is what I came here looking for, so upvote for you.

Comment: The alternative way is to specify pre-commit hook (pylint in this case) and file need to be checked: `pre-commit run pylint --files common/main.py`

Comment: This was the right answer for my google search, but the OP question was ambiguous.

Comment: Note that you need to have `git` installed, otherwise you would get this error: `An error has occurred: FatalError: git failed. Is it installed, and are you in a Git repository directory?`. It is relevant since I wanted to create a GitLab job that runs `pre-commit` to check if the repo was clean.

Comment: Note that if you have hooks which modify files (such as black) then you will potentially end up modifying a ton of files you didn't intend to with this command. You probably want those changes eventually, but not half way through an existing commit.

Answer (score 40):

For a single file:

```
pre-commit run --files YOUR_FILENAME
```

Comment: You also need to specify hook e.g. pre-commit run trailing-whitespace --files path\to\file

Answer (score 14):

Just run `git commit`. You don't have to add anything before doing this, hence in the end you get the message `no changes added to commit`.

Comment: At least for me it just says `Skipped` for all the commit hooks in that case. (might depend on which method / way you use for the pre-commit hooks, we use the Python package named `pre-commit`)

Comment: @mozzbozz
by default it will run only on changed files, I think. Run pre-commit run --all-files to confirm you can enforce the full repo scan

Comment: Please delete this answer. It completely misses the all the points made in some of the more useful answers above.

Answer (score 2):

In recent git releases, you can use the git hook run command to accomplish at least some of this. Check out the command at [enter link description here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hook)