# Run a husky git hook manually (without triggering it w/git command)

Tags: javascript, git, githooks, husky

I'm setting up a node project with [`husky`](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and I want to have a git-hook script run manually, without having to trigger it in git.

Example:

My package.json has the following:

```
{
...
    "scripts": {
        "precommit": // something goes here
    }
...
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
...
}
```

If I run `npm run precommit`, the `lint-staged` hook step runs, *WITHOUT* the commit actually occurring in git.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just call `lint-staged` command, `"precommit": "lint-staged"`

Comment: That didn't work, but @VonC's answer did (`bash .git/hooks/pre-commit`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be possible, since [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48301424/6309) illustrates you can simply call the `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

So as long as you are calling the hook directly, with its full path, you would run whatever it contains.

Comment: Thank you sir. I thought I combed through SO but missed that one. :/

Comment: @n8jadams No problem. I have been combing through SO since the dawn of time.

Comment: honestly I feel like husky should have a shortcut for this, like `pre-commit` does.

Answer (score 0):

If `pre-commit` is installed globally, you can just run this in the terminal:

```bash
pre-commit run --all-files
```